# Bored with Foucault, exhausted by Derrida, interested in the works of Serres, Deleuze, Latour

Tags: continental-philosophy

Is this (from [Barry Allen](http://www.humanities.mcmaster.ca/~philos/people/profile_allen.php)'s [letter to prospective graduate students](http://www.humanities.mcmaster.ca/~philos/people/letter_allen.php)) just an individual assessment or the expression of a wider pattern for understanding the complicated landscape of continental (French) philosophy? If the second, how could the pattern be stated in abstract form, i.e. without reference to those specific names?

> A frank admission of prejudices might be useful in deciding whether we
>   can work together. After some effort I have decided that I never want
>   to read Lyotard again. I have never read Levinas and nothing I have
>   heard makes me want to start. I have the same reaction to Badiou. I
>   think phenomenology is philosophically empty. I don't think Hegel or
>   Heidegger have anything to say to us anymore. I find it difficult to
>   take Freud as seriously as I need to to take Lacan seriously. I am
>   bored with Foucault, and exhausted by Derrida.
>
> On the other hand, I am very interested in the work of Michel Serres,
>   Gilles Deleuze, and Bruno Latour. Nietzsche still seems imminently
>   worth thinking about in connection with pretty much anything. I have
>   recently become deeply impressed with the neglected philosophy of
>   Bergson.

Comment: Even when I agree with many of Allen's aversions and prejudices, he does not more than just expressing his personal view and experience. His statement lacks any argument. - What is your question now? Shall we provide the missing arguments and find the common denominator for Lyotard, Levinas, Badiou, Hegel, Heidegger, Freud, Lacan, Foucault, Derrida? - Instead, could you pick up please one or two precise questions for this blog?

Comment: I didn't take this post on his website to be trying to argue generally so much as saying, if you want to write on these people, find someone else (along with a frank off-the-cuff style assessment of why -- probably so people don't imagine he could be convinced).

Comment: I don't think its a serious critique of the continental tradition; or to be fair, an explicitly serious critique: after all Freud influenced Lacan, and Derrida Deleuze - perhaps he wants new perspectives? Most of the philosophers he mentions have been around some time ie Hegel, Heidegger and Levinas.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because well, in context, he's just explaining what sort of graduate students he wants to have write with him. While this might reflect his views, it's not really a well-developed argument, so we're just reading between the line to guess.

Answer (score 2):

I'm really not sure what is intended,but isn't this part of a general frustration with the trajectory of subject-centered ontologies since Kant, and the seeming political dead-end of constructivism, hermeneutics, and textual analysis? One impulse seems to be the recovery of some sort of non-dogmatic attachment to the natural sciences, and hence to "nature" of some sort. More of a poplar "mood" than a new classification.